# Loop queried result

Tags: asp-classic

I'm totally new to asp. Sorry, if it's really basic but I couldn't find through my research.

I want to query Table_A by ID and NAME. (ID is PK, Name is optional)
then if ID is found but Name is null, I want to use that ID to query from other table.

```
Select * 
From Table_A;
```

gives me

```
ID    NAME
1     PAUL
2     BOB
3     NULL
```

Then save it into somewhere like Cursor in Stored Procedure.
Then during the loop, ID has empty name so run
    Select * From Table_B where ID = 3;

If I tag something, please help out to tag correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do 2 queries; you can instead do this:

```
select coalesce(a.name,b.name) as name
      , a.id 
from table_a a left join table_b b on b.id=a.id;
```

This will return the name from table a if not null; otherwise from table b.